# C++ Inline lambda argument

Tags: c++, lambda, inline

Consider the followng code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

inline void readandrun(function<void(int)> callback) {
    int i;
    i = 1;
    callback(i);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef LAMBDA
    readandrun([](int i){ printf("the read number is: %d\n",i);});
#else
    int i;
    i = 1;
    printf("the read number is: %d\n",i);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with

```
g++ -DLAMBDA -O2 -std=c++17 -S test.cpp -o test_long.S
```

Yields code involving jumps while

```
g++ -O2 -std=c++17 -S test.cpp -o test_short.S
```

Does not. Which kind of makes sense but is it possible to tell the compiler to inline the lambda argument since it's known at compile time? I would be willing to switch compilers but for completeness:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can allow to take function pointer instead of `std::function` as your argument, you can make your function `constexpr`:

```
constexpr void readandrun(void(*callback)(int)) {
    int i = 1; // can't use uninitialized variables in constexpr function
    callback(i);
}
```

[See the assembly online](https://godbolt.org/z/7W4EqG)

Note that only non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers. For capturing lambdas see [Fureeish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63530295/7976805). Also, `constexpr` functions have some limitations, but on the other hand compiler will execute them at compile time if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually a capturing lambda was inlined as long as `readandrun` is marked as `constexpr`: https://godbolt.org/z/dnoE5T

Answer (score 10):

> [...] is it possible to tell the compiler to inline the lambda argument since it's known at compile time?

Highly unlikely (in other words - **no**), which is mainly because you use `std::function` which, due to it's implementation's nature, uses *type erasure* and achieves this with **dynamic allocation**. When you call it, a virtual call is made so there is a jump. In order to inline the code, you may switch to:

```
template <typename Callback>
inline void readandrun(Callback callback) {
    int i;
    i = 1;
    callback(i);
}
```

That way, the lambda's exact type is deduced and the code is perfectly fine for inlineability.

---

Remember - lambda's type is never `std::function`. It's (the `std::function`) merely a wrapper around a callable with actual type erased.

Comment: I think using emplates is actually a good idea but turns out the trick was to mark `readandrun` as `constexpr` (and `std::function` obviously doesn't play well with that).